# How to do something like Drop Down Navigation in Android (since it looks like it has become deprecated?)

Tags: android, user-interface, drop-down-menu, navigation

**Edit: I also asked a related question here: [Android: How can I navigate from one "detail" to another "detail", while having the "Up" button go back to the "Master" list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019377/android-how-can-i-navigate-from-one-detail-to-another-detail-while-having)**

---

How do I make one of these on my app? **In my particular instance, I want to use a drop down menu to filter screens on my "Detail" view of my "Master-Detail" design pattern, and having a drawer seems kind of weird for that case, although it looks like Drop-Down-Menus have become deprecated and replaced with Navigation Drawers.**

[image]

I found a vague tutorial here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html , but I can't find any good Stack Overflow questions or any good tutorials on the web that demonstrate this.

I'm also concerned if it has really been deprecated. I went to my Google Calendar app, and found out that it has been replaced with a "drawer" like so:
[image]

[image]

I just want something that "filters" what to show on the screen, similar to this idea.

On Google's deprecated web page, it says:

> Implement ActionBar.OnNavigationListener to define the behavior that occurs when the user selects an item from the list.

And it links to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.OnNavigationListener.html,

which says:

> This interface is deprecated. Action bar navigation modes are
>   deprecated and not supported by inline toolbar action bars. Consider
>   using other common navigation patterns instead.

I went to the link, http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html, and couldn't find anything like the drop down menu. It mostly talked about whether you should click "Up" vs. "Back" buttons.

So, **How to do something like Drop Down Navigation in Android (since it looks like it has become deprecated?)**  Do I just have to start using drawers? In my particular instance, I want to use a drop down menu to filter screens on my "Detail" view of my "Master-Detail" design pattern, and having a drawer seems kind of weird for that case.

Comment: please check it out http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/07/android-actionbar-drop-down-navigation.html

Comment: @RajanBhavsar When I type in that example, I get the problem that "setNavigationMode" and "NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST" are both deprecated. That article is from 2013.

Comment: please check http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-drop-down-navigation-to-action-bar-in-android/ and i will try to find without depreciated code also

Comment: I already saw that article, and when I tried it, I got the message "getActionBar().setNavigationMode is deprecated". That article is from 2012 so it's outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With the API 21 the method setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST) is deprecated.**

The best way to work with a spinner is to use a Toolbar like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

You can find an example in the [Google IO 2014](https://github.com/google/iosched)

Comment: Can you put the specific example and all the components necessary for it to work? And maybe a screen shot, because I don't know what that Toolbar looks like.

Comment: After googling "Android toolbar," I found a helpful example that shows a spinner for navigation on a newer android version, so I think I know what you are talking about now. https://blog.danielbetts.net/2015/01/02/material-design-spinner-toolbar-style-fix/

Comment: I just didn't know that it has gotten a new name, "Toolbar spinner" instead of "dropdown navigation".